# UICollectionView with section headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, header, uicollectionview

Does anyone have an idea why I am getting this **Error**,

> "No visible @interface for 'UICollectionViewController' declares the
>   selector 'layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind

any help would be greatly appreciated..

Not sure where the error is coming from, I am getting it on the lines that have

```
[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:..

    - (NSArray *) layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {

        NSMutableArray *answer = [[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect] mutableCopy];

        NSMutableIndexSet *missingSections = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
        for (NSUInteger idx=0; idx<[answer count]; idx++) {
            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = answer[idx];

            if (layoutAttributes.representedElementCategory == UICollectionElementCategoryCell) {
                [missingSections addIndex:layoutAttributes.indexPath.section];  // remember that we need to layout header for this section
            }
            if ([layoutAttributes.representedElementKind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {
                [answer removeObjectAtIndex:idx];  // remove layout of header done by our super, we will do it right later
                idx--;
            }
        }

        // layout all headers needed for the rect using self code
        [missingSections enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:idx];
            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = [self layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader atIndexPath:indexPath];
            [answer addObject:layoutAttributes];
        }];

        return answer;
    }

    - (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind atIndexPath:indexPath];
        if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {
            UICollectionView * const cv = self.collectionView;
            CGPoint const contentOffset = cv.contentOffset;
            CGPoint nextHeaderOrigin = CGPointMake(INFINITY, INFINITY);

            if (indexPath.section+1 < [cv numberOfSections]) {
                UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *nextHeaderAttributes = [super layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind atIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:indexPath.section+1]];
                nextHeaderOrigin = nextHeaderAttributes.frame.origin;
            }

            CGRect frame = attributes.frame;
            if (self.scrollDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical) {
                frame.origin.y = MIN(MAX(contentOffset.y, frame.origin.y), nextHeaderOrigin.y - CGRectGetHeight(frame));
            }
            else { // UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal
                frame.origin.x = MIN(MAX(contentOffset.x, frame.origin.x), nextHeaderOrigin.x - CGRectGetWidth(frame));
            }
            attributes.zIndex = 1024;
            attributes.frame = frame;
        }
        return attributes;
    }

    - (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [self layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind atIndexPath:indexPath];
        return attributes;
    }
    - (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [self layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind atIndexPath:indexPath];
        return attributes;
    }

    - (BOOL) shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBound {
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: @chris.. please let me know where I introduced new errors so that I can update my knowledge. made it uppercase without any reason. that was not the major edit. I updated a sentence & few words. Sorry if it disturbed you

Answer (score 0):

Well the method don't exist in UITableViewController. It's a class level method on UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes so if you want to change it you need to subclass that class and also it's a class level method so use '+' not '-'.

Comment: I am using it in a UICollectionViewController. What I did was create a subclass like you said, then set the Layout to custom. and made the class set the class to the class I just created. its not working though..the cells are just displayed with 5 cells per row and space between them

Comment: Have you overridden isEquals on your UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes subclass? The subclassing notes in the documentation states that you have to override it in order to make it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

All these methods have to be implemented by your subclass of UICollectionViewLayout, not by your controller.

These methods allow the UICollectionView to ask the subclass of UICollectionViewLayout how to position the cells and the supplementary views (headers for example).

You need 2 different classes, a subclass of UICollectionViewLayout and a controller that implements the UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDataSource protocols and that provides the data (ie. number of cells, number of sections, the actual cells, etc.).

The particular error that you see is caused by this line:

```
[self layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind atIndexPath:indexPath];
```

`self` (ie. `UICollectionViewController`) does not define this method in its .h (and it shouldn't).